# How can I update a Python program running on Raspberry Pis remotely via 3G connections?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, gps, 3g

I am currently developing a Python program for a Raspberry Pi. This Raspberry is meant to control a solar panel. In fact, there will be many Raspberry Pis controlling solar panels and they will be connected to each others by RJ wires. The idea is that every Raspberry has the same status; there is not any "server" Raspberry and "client" Raspberry.

The program will receive GPS data, i.e. position, time...

Except for the GPS data, the Raspberry Pis will not have direct internet access. However, it will be possible to plug a 3G key in order to gain access to internet.

The problem is the following: I want to update my python program remotely, by internet provided by my 3G key (the solar panels are in a field, and I'm home for instance so I do not want to drive a hundred miles to get my Raspberry Pis back and update them manually...).

Is it possible to make the update remotely considering that I do not have a real "server" in my network of Raspberry Pis?

Comment: [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: if it is just a module, you can send the file and reload: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a server (or it can be just file-share service). If I got it correctly you need to access Raspberry Pis that connect to the internet via 3G. There are three options I see:

1. Connect to them via a VPN;
2. Write script that always be checking for new update for your app from an HTTP/FTP file-sharing server;
3. Use reverse-shell, but working depends on NAT specs that uses 3G provider.